# Count posts for each category

Tags: mysql

I have 3 MySQL tables:

Table1: Posts

```
id | date | postname | content
1 | 2014-07-17 | Post 1 | Content of post 1
2 | 2014-07-18 | Post 2 | Content of post 2
3 | 2014-07-19 | Post 3 | Content of post 3
```

Table2: Categories

```
id | category
1 | Category 1
2 | Category 2
3 | Category 3
```

Table3: Connection

```
id | post_id | category_id
1 | 1 | 1
2 | 1 | 2
3 | 2 | 2
4 | 2 | 3
5 | 3 | 1
6 | 3 | 2
7 | 4 | 3
```

I'm trying to display category names with number of posts to each category: example in this way:

```
Category 1 - 2 posts
Category 2 - 2 Posts
category 3 - 3 posts
```

I'm trying something like:

```
Select * FROM posts
inner join 
connection on...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you just need the post count per category, you don't need to join the `posts` table. Joining to the connection table and grouping by the category will suffice.

```
select c.category, count(*)
from categories c
join connection co on co.category_id = c.id
group by c.category
```

Comment: Thank you, tested and working, just one more question now to display with php the category name? do i need to echo $row['c.category']

Comment: @Elona echo `$row['category']` (the table alias `c` isn't included)

Comment: What about still showing the categories that doesn't have any posts yet? You need `left join` I think. But the `count(*)` will give a wrong result. So the count should be: `count(co.post_id)`.